# Send An Email to Admin on User Profile Completion

Tags: functions, profiles

I am trying to write a function that emails the site admin when a user profile reaches 100%.

I found this piece of code that sends an admin email when a post is published:

```
function send_admin_email($post_id){
    $to = 'admin@email.here';
    $subject = 'mail subject here';
    $message = "your message here ex: new post published at: ".get_permalink($post_id);
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
}
```

And I have this value from the profile plugin I'm using:

```
$user_progress['completion_percentage'] == 100
```

Instead of sending an email when a post is published, I need to send an email when a user's profile reaches 100%.

Unfortunately, it's over my head as to how to achieve what I want to do. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The problem you're going to have to overcome is WHERE/WHEN to execute a check for the profile completion value and if the check shows that the value is 100% you then send the email.  Since you're using a third party plugin for the profiles, you're going to have to check their documentation and see if there's a logical place to add your mail function.  For example, the profile plugin has a save methodology and that's probably where it updates the 'completion_percentage' value, so you'd look to hook into that process, check the value after it's increased and then send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you could simply call the WordPress function

`wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );`

when your var `$user_progress['completion_percentage']` equal 100 %.

```
<?php 
if( $user_progress['completion_percentage'] === 100 ) {
  // Complete your variables with original code
  $to = "youradminemail@domain.com";
  $subject = __("New user registration", "yourdomain");
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  $message = "A new user have completed his/her profile" . $user['id'];
  
  // Send the email
  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

}
?>
```

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: This will be heavily dependent on where it's placed though - you have to tie this functionality into the process that checks and updates the `$user_progress` function.  Can OP please show the code they wrote for the user as I'm assuming they have some custom fields/user meta data that they're recording.

Comment: Actually, I read it again, there's a third-party profile plugin, so OP will have to check with the plugin's devs to see if there's a place to hook into the plugin's process where this code can be executed - otherwise, it'll have to be a CRON that checks for newly completed profiles and I would strongly advise against that.